# Finding the best fit to an equation in color plot

Tags: python, plot

I have a set of 3D data (x,y,z) that can be represented in a color plot.

I am trying to trace a line on the color plot such that the data points that fall on the line best fits a fairly simple equation.

To approach this problem, I have in my mind to first to define a cost function to calculate a `chi-square` and then do an `optimization/minimization` with the cost function to find the `best fit`. But here in my problem, the best fit "parameter" is essentially an array of indices corresponding to the data points instead of some values. I am not entirely sure how to generate a "line" for each iteration (the line that traces across the color plot does not have an analytical form).

This feels like a problem to minimize a functional but I cannot yet figure out how to turn this into code. 
I would appreciate any help to solve this problem.

The color plot of sample data with a line tracing across it:

[image: Here is the screenshot]